# How can I write a algorithm that finds how many of a certain number is in a row in a list in python?

Tags: python

How can I write a algorithm that finds how many of a certain number is in a row in a list in python?

FOR EXAMPLE:

Input:
List = [0,1,1,1,0,1,1]
N = 1

Output:
3

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I count the occurrences of a list item?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2600191/how-can-i-count-the-occurrences-of-a-list-item)

Comment: It seems like you are looking for the *maximum* count of `1` in a row, otherwise how do you account for the two additional `1` values at the end? Are you looking for the max?

Comment: @MichaelButscher That's total, not in a row.

Answer (score 2):

Use `groupby` to group the identical items, and then find the `max` of the `len`s of the groups where the item equals `N`:

```
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> max(len(list(group)) for i, group in groupby([0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1]) if i == 1)
3
>>> max(len(list(group)) for i, group in groupby([0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1]) if i == 0)
1
```

Comment: in order to no waste space making a list to get how many there are, you can do `sum(1 for _ in group)`

Comment: @Copperfield I wouldn't call it "waste", more like "*spend* space on speed and simplicity".